# Prove or disprove when for any r,x $\in$ R and rx $\in$I where I is an ideal, then x $\in$ I?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ideals

Recall the definition of **ideal** I in a ring R;

- I is a subgroup of R under addition
- For any x $\in$ I and any r $\in$ R, rx $\in$ I and xr $\in$ I

My question is : Change the order

- If for any r,x $\in$ R and rx $\in$I where I is an ideal,
- Can we say that x $\in$ I? If Yes, please give a short proof, if not, give me a counterexample. Thanks

Comment: There's something off in your wording, you start by "for any $r,x\in R$" and then ask about "$x\in I$" as if $x$ was fixed, but it wasn't. Could you give a more precise statement of your question?

Comment: If you mean this as: "Fix an ideal $I\subseteq R$ and $x\in R.$ If we have $rx\in I$ for all $r\in R,$ can we say $x\in I$?" the answer is yes, assuming your rings have unity, as $x = 1\cdot x \in I.$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is an excellent question because it leads to the extremely important notion of a prime ideal. A proper ideal $\mathfrak p$ of a commutative ring $R$ is said to be prime when this condition $rx \in \mathfrak p$ implies $r \in \mathfrak p$ or $x \in \mathfrak p$, exactly as you stated. I can then answer your question by providing an example of a non-prime ideal. Indeed, the name "prime" is appropriate. Consider the ring $\mathbb Z$ and the ideal $4\mathbb Z \subseteq \mathbb Z$. $4 = 2 \cdot 2 \in 4 \mathbb Z$ but $2 \notin \mathbb Z$.

The fact that $4$ has a nontrivial prime factorization into $2^2$ is exactly why this works. Here's an exercise for you if you'd care to try it: prove that if $n \geq 2$ that $n \mathbb Z$ is a prime ideal if and only if $n$ is prime.